# Как заставить Google TTS правильно ставить ударения?

Tags: android, android-sdk, tts, android-text-to-speech

Использую [Google TTS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts) в приложении для Android.

Русский язык есть, но он неправильно ставит ударения в некоторых словах.
Пробовал расставлять апострофы типа: "Замо'к от за'мка", не помогает.
Есть ли решение?

Comment: Не пробовал "Замо+к от за+мка" ?

Comment: @MajorMeow не хочет. Знак "+" так и произносит )

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно только звучание, попробуйте поиграть словами.

Например можно отделить нужную букву например так "з'а'мок". В слове "шаровые" голос ставит удвоение "шарОвые", а нужно "шАровые". Я написал "шарвые", пропустил букву О и получилось очень даже хорошо. Так же я меняю предлог "в" на "ф", получается вполне прилично в звучании

Answer (score -2):

Надо ставить не апостроф, а знак ` (который на букве ё)